# How to search for "Not Contains" condition on collection of objects in RavenDB

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I'm new to the RavenDB and I am struck with a condition here.Basically this is what I want to achive I have a list of the employees in the RavenDB and I need to fetch employees who are not of the type "Contract".I tried to use basic linq query but I am unable to resolve the issue as I am geting exceptions like "Method Not Supported" and "Cannot understand how to translate ... etc".

This is what I have tried untill now.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var documentStore = new DocumentStore() { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDBConnectionString" })
            {
                documentStore.Initialize();
                /* using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
                {
                    session.Store(new User { Id = 1, Roles = new List<Role> { new Role { Type = UserType.Contract }, new Role { Type = UserType.Developer } } });
                    session.Store(new User { Id = 2, Roles = new List<Role> { new Role { Type = UserType.Permanent }, new Role { Type = UserType.Developer } } });
                    session.Store(new User { Id = 3, Roles = new List<Role> { new Role { Type = UserType.SeniorDeveloper }, new Role { Type = UserType.Manager } } });
                    session.Store(new User { Id = 4, Roles = new List<Role> { new Role { Type = UserType.Contract }, new Role { Type = UserType.SeniorDeveloper } } });
                    session.Store(new User { Id = 5, Roles = new List<Role> { new Role { Type = UserType.Permanent }, new Role { Type = UserType.Manager } } });
                    session.Store(new User { Id = 6, Roles = new List<Role> { new Role { Type = UserType.Contract }, new Role { Type = UserType.Developer } } });
                    session.SaveChanges();
                }*/

                using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
                {

                    //var nonContractEmployees = session.Query<User>().Where(x => !x.Roles.Exists(y => y.Type == UserType.Contract)).ToList();
                     var nonContractEmployees = session.Query<User>().Where(x => x.Roles.Count(y => y.Type == UserType.Contract) == 0).ToList();
                    // var nonContractEmployees = session.Query<User>().Where(x => !x.Roles.Contains(x.Roles.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Type == UserType.Contract))).ToList();
                    //var nonContractEmployees = session.Query<User>().Where(x => x.Roles.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Type == UserType.Contract) == null).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Role
    {
        public UserType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum UserType
    {
        Manager,
        Permanent,
        Contract,
        Developer,
        SeniorDeveloper
    }
```

I would really appretiate it if someone can help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: @PranayRana: none of those queries work for me

Comment: Try the google groups.  I'm sure there is a way around this but I'm having a hard time with it as well.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ravendb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 1**

```
var nonContractEmployees = session.Query<User>()
    .Where(x => !x.Roles.In(new [] {new Role { Type = UserType.Contract}))
    .ToList();
```

**Edit 2**

This works but isn't efficient.

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var nonContractEmployees = session.Query<User>()
        .ToList()
        .Where(x => x.Roles.Contains(
            new Role {Type = UserType.Contract},
            new RoleComparer()));                        
}

public class RoleComparer : IEqualityComparer<Role>
{
    public bool Equals(Role x, Role y)
    {
        return
            x == null && y == null ||
            x != null &&
            y != null &&
            x.Type == y.Type;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Role obj)
    {
        return
            obj == null
                ? 0
                : obj.Type.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: @M Afifi: it is not possible friend, "y" is of type "Role" not UserType

Comment: @M Afifi: thanks it working wrt what I have asked, but is there any way we can do it in server side itself? I would like to use statistics in the query if we are converting to a list that wont be possible. I think I will have to go for Indexes as Ayende suggested here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ravendb/LpSo3VdkavI . I am marking this as answer since this is working for what I have asked.

Comment: @wizzardz I was thinking of indexes too, but they're really being lazy.  Its a bug that needs to be fixed.  Their library is symmantically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var nonContractEmployees = session.Query<User>()
    .Where(x => !x.Roles.Any(y => y.Type == UserType.Contract))
    .ToList();
```

I've updated my Query with what it should be. (currently failing)

And I've submitted a failing test to Ayende to your query on the Google Group.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ravendb/LpSo3VdkavI

Comment: @MAfifi The logic is 'x.Roles.Any(..)' which would return true, then invert that with the ! to make it false. Any user who has that role (true) don't include them. That to me is a bug.

Comment: I am also seeing this behavior in 1.0.960